# Render hidden field instead of text field using Grails Fields plugin

Tags: grails

There are two text properties of various classes: createdBy and lastUpdatedBy.  They are just the user name of the logged in user.  They render using _widget.gsp in ${grails-app}/views/_fields/string/widget.gsp.  This is how _widget.gsp looks:

```
<g:if test="${property == 'createdBy' || property == 'lastUpdatedBy' }">
    <g:hiddenField name="${property}" value="${value}" />
</g:if>
<g:else>
        <input type="text" name="${property}" value="" <g:if test="${required}">required=""</g:if> id="${property}" />
</g:else>
```

Unfortunately the labels with the asterisks are still rendered. When trying to save it tells me createdBy and lastUpdatedBy are required, although they are in the page source as hidden fields with the right values filled in.

Also, is my treatment of 'required' correct?

Any idea of how to get rid of the labels and required asterisks for the hidden fields?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to do it:
Create this directory structure containing _wrapper.gsp:

> grails-app/views/${controller}/${action}/${property}/_wrapper.gsp

_wrapper.gsp looks like this:

```
<g:hiddenField name="${property}" value="${value}" />
```

You'll need this only for create and edit actions.  This means you can copy and paste this to where you need it. Simple, if one knows how to do it.